# What is wrong with my Scala code?

Tags: scala

In the following code I am trying to write a simple Scala program to test my recent learning on Scala.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter

object Solution {

    def getval(n: Int): Long = {
        val stdin = scala.io.StdIn
        var ans:Long = 0;
        var i = 0;

        for(i <- 1 to n){
            val str:String = stdin.readLine;
            val z:Int = stdin.readLine.trim.toInt;

            if(str.charAt(0)=='h'){
                if(z > 0) ans = ans + 1
            }
            else {
                if(z > ans) ans = ans + 2
            }
        }

        ans
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val stdin = scala.io.StdIn
        val n = stdin.readLine.trim.toInt
        val result = getval(n)
        println(result)

    }
}
```

When compiled, it keeps giving me a `No such file or directory` error. What is wrong with my code?

EDIT: The code compiles fine now. However, with the following input to the program, I am now getting a Java run time exception:

Input:

```
4
abs 2
xyz 1
tes 3
pop 6
```

Exception message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "xyz 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt(StringLike.scala:301)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt$(StringLike.scala:301)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on the exact error and how you are running it?  If you are trying to run the class file directly, you can't do that, it must be run with the scala command, so `scala Solution` to run the code.  (You can also run it with the `java` command but then you must also put the scala library onto the classpath.

Comment: "abs 2" cannot be converted to a number - you'd have to `.split(' ')` them, confirm that you get 2-element sequence, make sure that second element is a number. Basically do error handling.

Comment: @user3243499 if you have a new question please ask a new question, don't update an old one.

Answer (score 1):

you get an error because you provide a string

> xyz 1

to a line that assumes a string is an Integer

```
val z:Int = stdin.readLine.trim.toInt;
```

if your data looks like a string followed by space and a number you can

```
val z:Int = stdin.readLine.trim.split(' ').last.toInt
```

Specifically your first line str - reads the abs2 and then the second one tries to read the xyz 1